# How to get name of cipher?

Tags: c, openssl

I have problem with getting name of cipher. I read documentation about SSL_CIPHER_get_name and SSL_get_current_cipher, there is some differences, but I think that result is similar. However, I still don't understand how to use it in code, and I didn't find any examples. Could somebody help me? I also need to print it, but I don't know how. Here is my code:

```
SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl,sockfd);
SSL_connect(ssl);

SSL_CIPHER *cipher;
cipher = SSL_get_current_cipher(ssl);
SSL_CIPHER_get_name(cipher);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a connection is TLSv1 vs SSLv3 (SSL\_CIPHER\_description/SSL\_CIPHER\_get\_name)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656680/check-if-a-connection-is-tlsv1-vs-sslv3-ssl-cipher-description-ssl-cipher-get-n). And see the documentation on the functions at [`SSL_CIPHER_get_name`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CIPHER_get_name.html). Also see the source code for `s_client` located at `<openssl src>/apps/s_client.c`.

Comment: I have read this topic before I make this one, but I didn't find answer for my question. I don't know if this code which I posted is doing what I need, because I don't know how to print it out. I also read the documentation as I wrote in first post, but I am still not sure how to use it, and I didn't find any example. Thanks ;)

Comment: `SSL_CIPHER_get_name` returns a `const char*`. Try printing it. You can do so with `printf("Cipher name: %s", SSL_CIPHER_get_name(cipher) ? SSL_CIPHER_get_name(cipher) : "no cipher");`